# Mule Quartz Connector terminates abruptly after running for hours

Tags: mule, quartz-scheduler

My Mule Quartz Connector runs for several hours then terminates abruptly. I want the job to run continuously every 30 minutes past the hour. However, after running for several hours it suddenly terminates. I suspect it is related to the cronExpression but I am not sure which part will cause that to happen. I feel that the cronExpression has something that is making this happen, as it simply shuts the application down terminating the process.
Please help!!

Here is the quartz configuration:

```
<quartz:connector name="updateQuartzConnector" validateConnections="true" doc:name="Quartz">
    <receiver-threading-profile maxThreadsActive="1"/>
    <quartz:factory-property key="org.quartz.scheduler.instanceName" value="updateQuartzScheduler"/>
    <quartz:factory-property key="org.quartz.threadPool.class" value="org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool"/>
    <quartz:factory-property key="org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount" value="1"/>
    <quartz:factory-property key="org.quartz.scheduler.rmi.proxy" value="false"/>
    <quartz:factory-property key="org.quartz.scheduler.rmi.export" value="false"/>
    <quartz:factory-property key="org.quartz.jobStore.class" value="org.quartz.simpl.RAMJobStore"/>
</quartz:connector>
```

And here is the flow using the quartz configuration above:

```
 <flow name="processClientData" tracking:enable-default-events="true" processingStrategy="synchronous">
   <quartz:inbound-endpoint responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="30 minutes past hour" cronExpression="0 30/30 0/1 * * ?" 
         jobName="ProcessClientUpdates" repeatInterval="0" connector-ref="updateQuartzConnector">
   <quartz:event-generator-job/>
   </quartz:inbound-endpoint>
   <flow-ref name="process.client.data" />
</flow>
```

I show part of the flow, although this part works fine:

```
 <flow name="process.client.data" processingStrategy="synchronous">
  <db:select config-ref="ORACLE_CONFIG" doc:name="Check Customer existence in Database">
   <db:parameterized-query><![CDATA[SELECT first_name,last_name,email FROM contact 
     WHERE email=#[payload.email]]]></db:parameterized-query>
   </db:select>
    <enrich source="#[payload.size() > 0]" target="#[recordVars['exists']]"/>
    <enrich source="#[payload]" target="#[recordVars['dbRecord']]"/>
.......
 </flow>
```

Please help this issue is just perplexing

Answer (score 0):

The cron expression should be 0 30/30 * * *?